# What is Script Evaluation?

Tags: seo, web-development, javascript

"Reduce JavaScript Execution Time" is one of the generated issues Lighthouse can detect auditing any URL. Sometimes it's reporting a specific file is taking a lot of time in Script Evaluation phase.

[image]

I'm wondering  how i can fix the script? Basically I have a couple of questions in relation to that

- What is Script Evaluation time?
- Does the evaluation means downloading, parsing and compiling?
- Can the script evaluation affect the script execution?
- Can the script evaluation affect the script execution?

Comment: See also on [so]: [Lighthouse audit: Script evaluation vs Script Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882699/lighthouse-audit-script-evaluation-vs-script-parsing)  Which you answered, so why are you asking?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The question was originally in Stackoverfow and moved here before my answer. I updated my answer after posting the question here

Comment: I'm confused.   I don't see any moved questions.

Comment: Here is the original question that moved to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931506/what-is-script-evaluation